# Simplifying a SUM() across custom date quarters

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run the query below, the temp_08.members table created only features one column (Q4'10) which is the sum of all calcs. This is incorrect.

INSTEAD I am trying to create a separate column for each quarter with the sum(calc) for just data inside that quarter. For some reason the query below does not accomplish this.

Second, is there a more efficient way to write this query. I will have 20 quarters, and the only thing that changes in each is the column name (as Q4_16) and the dates for each select.

NOTE: I need to preserve the ability to define each quarter's dates. The 
quarters are fiscal quarters that don't always follow standard date intervals or patterns.

```
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q4_10,
brand
into   temp_08.members
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '09/30/2010' and date <= '12/29/2010'
GROUP BY brand

insert into temp_08.members
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q1_11,
brand
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '12/29/2010' and date <= '3/28/2011'
GROUP BY brand

insert into temp_08.members
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q2_11,
brand
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '3/28/2011' and date <= '6/30/2011'
GROUP BY brand

insert into temp_08.members
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q3_11,
brand
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '6/30/2011' and date <= '9/25/2011'
GROUP BY brand

insert into temp_08.members
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q4_11,
brand
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '9/25/2011' and date <= '12/31/2011'
GROUP BY brand
```

Comment: Do you have a table that defines the ranges for each quarter?

Comment: I need to run this query for close to 150 stocks, each stock has a different start/end to its fiscal quarter.  Is it most seamless to store such values in a separate table?

Comment: . . Yes, you should be storing this type of data in a reference table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really have a table that defines the quarters.  In a query, you can do this using a CTE:

```
with q(qqyy, firstday, lastday) as (
      (values ('Q4_10','2010-10-01', '2010-12-29'),
              . . .
      ))
SELECT q.qqyy, brand, sum(calc) as Q4_10,
into   temp_08.members
from temp_08.source s join
     q
     on s.date >= q.firstday and s.date <= q.lastday
GROUP BY q.qqyy, brand;
```

EDIT:

An an example of the CTE:

```
with q(qqyy, firstday, lastday) as (
      (values ('Q4_10', date '2010-10-01', date '2010-12-29'),
              ('Q1_11', date '2010-12-30', date '2011-03-28'),
              ('Q2_11', date '2011-03-29', date '2011-06-30')
      ))
select * from q
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff.  One question - the syntax of your CTE is throwing up an error when I implement it - any idea?  [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "values" Position: 38

Comment: @ZJAY . . . I assume you are replacing the `. . .` with the appropriate tuples for defining the quarters.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff: Your example of the CTE still returns [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "values" Position: 45. Have you tried to implement the query via postgresql? Thank you kindly

Comment: @ZJAY . . . As a matter of fact, I did test this in Postgres 9.5, and it works fine.

Comment: I tried using two separate IDEs and got the same error around "values."  By way of reference, both IDEs are using the following: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1115

Comment: Postgres 8 is pretty old . . . Perhaps you should do `select 'Q4_10' as qqyy, date '2010-10-01' as firstday, date '2010-12-29' as lastday union all . . .` instead of the `values()` short-hand.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a table with quarters and dates that each quarter covers (this would simplify the insertion a lot):

```
create table temp_08.quarters (
    quarter_col text
  , date_from   date
  , date_to     date
);

insert into temp_08.quarters 
  values 
    ('Q4_10', '2010-09-30', '2010-12-29'),
    ('Q1_11', '2010-12-29', '2011-03-28'),
    ...
;
```

Create your members table:

```
create table temp_08.members (
    brand       text
  , quarter_col text
  , calc_sum    bigint -- or whatever type you like
);
```

Then, you just insert it into your members table like that:

```
INSERT INTO temp_08.members ( brand, quarter_col, calc_sum )
  SELECT 
      s.brand
    , q.quarter_col
    , sum(s.calc) as calc_sum
  FROM temp_08.source s
  JOIN temp_08.quarters q ON s.date > q.date_from AND s.date <= q.date_to 
  GROUP BY s.brand, q.quarter_col;
```